# Combobox not rendering in wpf datafrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, combobox

I have my data grid "dgSubsytem" column defined like below

```
 <my:DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="cmbSubSysSupplier_SRV" Header="Supplier"  Width="160"                                            
                                         ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource}" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding SupplierId}"   />
```

As you see from the code i am having a combo box inside a grid .

Item source of this combo box is a datatable which is bound to it in the code behind .

Item source of the grid also another datatable bound in code behind .

code of binding item source of combobox in code behind is as follows

```
cmbSubSysSupplier_SRV.ItemsSource = dsComboBox.Tables[3].DefaultView;
cmbSubSysSupplier_SRV.DisplayMemberPath="FullName" ;
cmbSubSysSupplier_SRV.SelectedValuePath = "SupplierId";
```

Problem is combo box itself not rendering . But I can see the value of the Supplier rendered as text  . What is the problem?

Comment: What does the Datagrid look like?

Comment: Sorry, I mean, what does the Datagrid code look like?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 parts here:

List of values to be populated in ComboBox: ItemsSource, should be bound using a StaticResource, with a `List<X>` fields exposed from your ViewModel.

The actual value (here X) should be bound to SelectedItemBinding using binding to data item.

No binding in code behind required.

Comment: But I have my combo box binding entries in datatable "dtcmb" . AND grid binding datatable in dtGrid  . How can I code this . i am new to wpf and binding . Just can u show how ?

Answer (score 0):

At what point does your code-behind stuff run?

You're setting the `ItemsSource` in two places - in the XAML and in the Code-Behind. Whichever one runs second will overwrite the value of the first one, so only the last value set will be used.

I suspect your XAML is getting run last, and `RelativeSource` is probably not a property on your `DataContext`, so your `ComboBox` ends up being bound to nothing.

To fix it, simply remove your `ItemsSource` binding in the XAML for the `DataGridComboBoxColumn`

```
<my:DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="cmbSubSysSupplier_SRV" 
                           Header="Supplier" Width="160"
                           SelectedValueBinding="{Binding SupplierId}"  />
```

In addition, the `DefaultView` of a `DataTable` will return an object of type `DataView`, and `DataView` does not have properties called `FullName` or `SupplierId`, so your `SelectedValuePath` and `DisplayMemberPath` properties won't work.

I'd recommend building a list of `KeyValuePair<int,string>` out of your data items, and bind your `ComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource` to that list, then switch the `SelectedValuePath` to `"Key"` and the `DisplayMemberPath` to `"Value"`

Comment: I removed but its still the same

Comment: @KuntadyNithesh See the update to my answer - You likely have items in your `ComboBox`, but they are not being displayed because `DataView` does not have a property called `FullName` to display.

Answer (score 0):

I personally fought with DataGridComboBoxColumn for long time and i think the way is to use `DataGridTemplateColumn`.
 Here is an exemple :

Looks a lot of code but evective.
Put the collection as resource :

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="StructuresCollection" Source="{Binding StructuresList, Mode=OneTime}"/>
</Grid.Resources>

 <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Structure" >
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Structures.Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate >
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox x:Name="CStructures" SelectedItem="{Binding Structures}"  DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValue="{Binding IDStructure, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedValuePath="{Binding IDStructure}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource StructuresCollection}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```